# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lcd'

Tags: python, attributes, lcd

I am trying to make Python code on my RPi 3B+ where it displays the time and date. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import I2C_LCD_driver
import time


mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()


while True:
    mylcd.lcd_display_string(time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p'), 1)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string(time.strftime('%a %b %d, 20%y'), 2)
```

I got this for an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_clock.py", line 7, in <module>
    mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lcd'
```

Comment: You did not import the right module. Use `python -v ...` to debug.

Comment: Can you post where you got the I2C_LCD_Driver code, and how you downloaded/installed it?

Comment: I got it from GitHub.com